# Pls help to solve this question from probability

Tags: probability-distributions

Of the $40$ employees at a certain company, $20$ are available to meet on Monday $(M)$, $17$ are available to meet on wednesday $(W)$, and $8$ are available neither on Monday nor wednesday $(\overline{M\cup W})$. What is the probability that a randomly selected employee is available to meet on both Monday and Wednesday $(M \cap W)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E$ denote the set of employees.

Let $M\subseteq E$ denote the set of employees available for monday.

Let $W\subseteq E$ denote the set of employees available for wednesday.

Now use the equality:$$|W|+|M|=|W\cup M|+|W\cap M|$$

To get some insight make a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be the set of people available on monday and $W$ be the set of people available on wednesday.
$$P(M)=\dfrac{20}{40}$$
$$P(W)=\dfrac{17}{40}$$
Now $P(\overline{M\cup W})=\dfrac{8}{40}$
$$\Rightarrow P(M\cup W)=\dfrac{32}{40}$$
$$P(M\cap W)=P(M)+P(W)-P(M\cup W)$$
$$P(M\cap W)=\dfrac{20}{40}+\dfrac{17}{40}-\dfrac{32}{40}$$
$$P(M\cap W)=\dfrac{1}{8}$$
Therefore the probability that a randomly selected employee is available on both monday and wednesday is $\dfrac{1}{8}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$40 =\underbrace{|M| +|W| -|M\cap W|}_{|M\cup W|} + |(M\cup W)^c|$$

This is nothing more than the statement that the Venn diagram includes all employees.